# Erro na divisão por grupos ramdomicamente

Tags: javascript

Bom dia. Estou fazendo um código em javascript, para dividir um array de nomes em grupos. É apenas um exemplo, mas irei usar num sistema para o futebol que participo.

Quero fazer tudo dinamicamente, mas vamos por partes: Tenho esse código, que divide por times (usei nome de medicamentos pois ja tinha numa lista aqui), e queria que fosse dividido por numero definido (4 times de 6 participantes). Só que está gerando um object com 2 arrays de 5 nomes, e 3 arrays de 4 nomes.

Poderiam me ajudar a fazer o código gerar 3 times de 6 participantes, e o ultimo time de 4 participantes?

```
var array = ['TRAXONOL 100MG',
  'CETOMICOSS 200MG',
  'CETONEO 200MG',
  'UROVIT 100MG',
  'UROVIT 100MG',
  'UNI VIR 200MG',
  'AFTILIV',
  'LEIBA SACHE',
  'LEIBA CAPS',
  'SUPOSITORIO GLICERINA',
  'GLICERIN',
  'SEAKALM LIQUIDO',
  'SEAKALM COMP',
  'VERTIGIUM 10MG',
  'FLUCANIL 150MG',
  'TENSALIV 10MG',
  'FONT D GTS',
  'VITACIN 1G',
  'CENEVIT 1G',
  'TONICO VITAL',
  'NUTRI HOMEM',
  'NUTRI MAIS LIQUIDO'
];

function distributePlayers(names, numberOfTeams) {
  var ret = {};
  var teamCounter = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    if (!ret["array" + teamCounter]) {
      ret["array" + teamCounter] = [];
    }
    ret["array" + teamCounter].push(names[i]);
    if (++teamCounter == numberOfTeams) {
      teamCounter = 0;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

var arrays = distributePlayers(array, 4);
console.log(arrays)
```

Exemplo aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/guilhermelirio85/0djLyg9p/

Agradeco!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso funciona:

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    if (!ret["array" + teamCounter]) {
        ret["array" + teamCounter] = [];
    }
    ret["array" + teamCounter].push(names[i]);
    if (ret["array" + teamCounter].length == Math.ceil(names.length / numberOfTeams)) {
        teamCounter++;
    }
}
```

O código preenche as equipes uma a uma até que o tamanho desejado seja atingido (ou não haja mais equipes).

http://jsfiddle.net/0djLyg9p/3/

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado e vou estudar melhor o código!

Comment: Esse `==` em vez de `>=` ai na comparação do final - não vai dar problema quando a divisão  de  `names.length / numberOfTeams` não for inteira?

Comment: JavaScript não tem divisão inteira. `Math.ceil()` sempre retorna um inteiro.

Answer (score 1):

Da maneira como você esta fazendo esta percorrendo todos os jogadores e distribuindo entre os times.

Acho que seria mais performático você percorrer somente o array de times e distribuir os jogadores, assim o loop seria bem menor.

Veja exemplo abaixo

```js
let itens = ['TRAXONOL 100MG',
  'CETOMICOSS 200MG',
  'CETONEO 200MG',
  'UROVIT 100MG',
  'UROVIT 100MG',
  'UNI VIR 200MG',
  'AFTILIV',
  'LEIBA SACHE',
  'LEIBA CAPS',
  'SUPOSITORIO GLICERINA',
  'GLICERIN',
  'SEAKALM LIQUIDO',
  'SEAKALM COMP',
  'VERTIGIUM 10MG',
  'FLUCANIL 150MG',
  'TENSALIV 10MG',
  'FONT D GTS',
  'VITACIN 1G',
  'CENEVIT 1G',
  'TONICO VITAL',
  'NUTRI HOMEM',
  'NUTRI MAIS LIQUIDO'
];


function distributePlayers(names, numberOfTeams) {
  let itens = names.slice(0)

  // Quantidade de jogadores por time
  const numberOfPlayers = Math.ceil(itens.length / numberOfTeams)

  // Cria o array de times e distribui os jogadores
  const final = Array.from(Array(numberOfTeams).keys())
            .map(p => itens.splice(0, numberOfPlayers))

  return final
}

var arrays = distributePlayers(itens, 6)

console.log(arrays)
```

Comment: Perfeita a resposta também, muito obrigado!!

Comment: Uma dúvida: porque se eu colocar a criação do array dentro de uma função, só executa uma vez?

Comment: Porque no exemplo eu estou usando `splice` para adicionar os itens no grupo.
O splice `remove` os elementos do item original.
O que você pode fazer é dentro da função antes de começar é `clonar` o array de jogadores para uma variável e vai removendo o itens dela mantendo o array original intacto. `let cloneItens = Object.assign({}, itens)`

Comment: Alterei a resposta para função para ficar de acordo com o exemplo

Comment: Poderia deixar daquele jeito, @Danilo. Irei fazer uns testes!!

Comment: Alias, agora que percebi que não embaralha os nomes do array. Mas irei ver como fazer isso. Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: O ideal é você deixar a responsabilidade do método somente para distribuir os jogadores, já passando para ele os jogadores embaralhados.

Comment: Pode usar essa função para embaralhar https://gist.github.com/Atlas7/c04bbef301dfce601f36324886635558